# Swissranger with OpenNI

Tags: openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone worked on using OpenNI tracking algorithms with Swissranger data or any PointCloud data? I am able to obtain PointCloud data published by swissranger but not sure how I can use with OpenNI, well, I'll try to figure out something but in the meantime wanted to see if anyone has worked on it already.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9062/swissranger-with-openni/) by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 284 on 2011-02-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, getting the SwissRanger to work with the OpenNI tracking algorithms, i.e. NITE, will be difficult.  To the best of my understanding, the NITE binary uses the PrimeSense-specific driver API, not just the OpenNI API.  In other words, it is not sufficient to be OpenNI-compliant to make use of the NITE capabilities.

I believe Omek Interactive is making their own tracking library that is compatible with the SwissRanger and other devices, but using their software will require a license.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blueskin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26/blueskin/) on 2011-02-15**:
Thanks kwc.